# Detect mobile user agent from classic ASP and redirect on session start

Tags: mobile, asp-classic, user-agent

I'd like to detect a mobile user agent and redirect them when the session starts in a classic ASP app.  Does anyone know a good way to pull this off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-asp

```
sub is_mobile()
  Dim Regex, match
  Set Regex = New RegExp
     With Regex
        .Pattern = "(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|pda|mobile|mini|palm|ipad)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
      End With
   match = Regex.test(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
   If match Then
      return True
   Else
      return False
   End If
End Sub
```

**Disclaimer:* the code may not work, as I have no method to test it and little knowledge of classic ASP.

Comment: If match should change to If match "then"  you missing a then!

Comment: Note, this code has a few bugs in it. @Zeez G's code is the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for a way to do this myself.  After taking the code already here I found a few issues (nothing special, just probably mixing languages, a thing I do regularly).  Here's the altered version corrected for Classic ASP.

```
 Function Is_Mobile()
  Set Regex = New RegExp
  With Regex
    .Pattern = "(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|pda|mobile|mini|palm|ipad)"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
  End With
  Match = Regex.test(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
  If Match then
    Is_Mobile = True
  Else
    Is_Mobile = False
  End If
End Function
```

Notice I didn't declare the two variables, I know it's lazy but as ASP isn't Option Explicit I find it a useful convenience.

This is now working like a charm on my page for mobile detection, as follows:

```
<%If Is_Mobile() then%>
  <META NAME="viewport" CONTENT="initial-scale = 0.6, user-scalable = no">
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/CSS/Mobile.css" />
<%Else%>
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="CSS/Default.css" />
<%End If%>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Updated for android support

```
Function is_mobile()
  Dim Regex, match
  Set Regex = New RegExp
     With Regex
        .Pattern = "(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|pda|mobile|mini|palm|ipad|Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPod|Palm|Symbian)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
      End With
   match = Regex.test(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
   If match then
      is_mobile=True
   Else
      is_mobile=False
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me ..

```
    <%
dim u,b,v
set u=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
set b=new RegExp
set v=new RegExp
b.Pattern="(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino"
v.Pattern="1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg( 13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-"
b.IgnoreCase=true
v.IgnoreCase=true
b.Global=true
v.Global=true
if b.test(u) or v.test(Left(u,4)) then response.redirect("http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile") end if
%>
```

Source http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Note, this will not work for tablets see the About link on detectmobilebrowsers.com or just add: |android|ipad|playbook|silk to the end of the first pattern