# Mobile Request Detection and Redirect to Mobile Pages in Asp (Active Server Pages)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vbscript

I have a web application which already created in asp (Active Server Pages) and now a part of that web application module is converted to a mobile site (which normally approves or reject the invoice) so whenever a request comes from a mobile device i want to transfer the request to a mobile site so how can i detect the device in my asp login so i can redirect the request to mobile login page... ??

Answer (score 1):

You will need to see what User Agent you are getting. As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034697/how-can-i-detect-if-the-request-is-coming-from-a-mobile-browser-in-my-asp-net-mv) SO Thread:

```
private static string[] mobileDevices = new string[] {"iphone","ppc"
                                                      "windows ce","blackberry",
                                                      "opera mini","mobile","palm"
                                                      "portable","opera mobi" };

public static bool IsMobileDevice(string userAgent)  
{  
    // TODO: null check
    userAgent = userAgent.ToLower();  
    return mobileDevices.Any(x => userAgent.Contains(x));
}
```

Update: I do not have much knowledge of ASP but I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836203/detect-mobile-user-agent-from-classic-asp-and-redirect-on-session-start) should put you on the right track.

Comment: My mobile site is in asp.net but my existing site is in asp so how can i add this in my asp pages which is my login.asp page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mobile ESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/?page_id=2) library for this. Even ported to [ASP Classic](https://bitbucket.org/mbarrero/mobileesp-classic-asp) ;).

Used the ASP Classic port a few times and works like a charm.