# Detect iPad in ASP Classic/Legacy

Tags: asp-classic, browser-detection

What is the best way to detect iPad in ASP Classic/Legacy.

Preferably a method that returns true or false.

Comment: I'd say the user agent identification is your best (and quite possibly only) bet. Maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836203/detect-mobile-user-agent-from-classic-asp-and-redirect-on-session-start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function is_iPad()
    Dim user_agent
    user_agent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")

    If InStr(1, user_agent, "ipad", 1) Then
        is_iPad = true
    Else
        is_iPad = false
    End If
End Function
```