# Determine device for application in classic asp

Tags: regex, asp-classic, user-agent

I want to determine, which device is used for my application. I want to see if it is a

- Phone
- Table
- PC

Even though there are only a couple of valid options (we have fixed devices for everything), I want to make it as dynamic as possible.

I found a similar question here: [Detect mobile user agent from classic ASP and redirect on session start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836203/detect-mobile-user-agent-from-classic-asp-and-redirect-on-session-start)

I adepted on that and wrote the following function, to check what device is currently visiting my site. However, I think it is kinda messy since it is so "static" when it comes to the regexp's

This is what I came up with:

```
public function checkUserAgent()
    Set Regex = New RegExp
    With Regex
        .Pattern = "(Mobile\sSafari|Linux;\sAndroid)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    Match = Regex.test(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
    If Match then
        user_agent = "Phone"
    End If

    Set Regex = New RegExp
    With Regex
        .Pattern = "(windows\sNT)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    Match = Regex.test(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
    If Match then
        user_agent = "PC"
    End If

    Set Regex = New RegExp
    With Regex
        .Pattern = "(ipad)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    Match = Regex.test(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
    If Match then
        user_agent = "Tablet"
    End If

end function
```

My question now: It seems like the code for the RegExp are redundant. How would I improve that? How could I possibly make this more compact, with the same result? I need to get the user-agent-type, so I can update my DB and keep counting, how many devices / types are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure it more like this.

```
dim device
device = checkUserAgent
response.write device

function checkUserAgent()

    dim user_agent
    user_agent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")

    if reTest(user_agent, "(Mobile\sSafari|Linux;\sAndroid)") then
        checkUserAgent = "Phone"
    elseif reTest(user_agent, "(windows\sNT)") then
        checkUserAgent = "PC"
    elseif reTest(user_agent, "(ipad)") then
        checkUserAgent = "Tablet"
    end if

end function

function reTest(subject, pattern)

    dim re, returnVal
    returnVal = false

    Set re = New RegExp
    With re
        .Pattern = pattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    If re.test(subject) then
        returnVal = true
    End If
    Set re = Nothing

    reTest = returnVal 

end function
```

Or, if you get more granular with your device types and end up with a lot more of them, it might be easier to manage with a dictionary. In that case checkUserAgent could look more like:

```
function checkUserAgent()

    dim user_agent, d

    user_agent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
    set d = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    d.add "Phone",  "(Mobile\sSafari|Linux;\sAndroid)"
    d.add "PC",     "(windows\sNT)"
    d.add "Tablet", "(ipad)"

    for each k in d.keys
        if (reTest(user_agent, d.item(k))) then
            checkUserAgent = k
            exit for
        end if
    next

end function
```